# Is it worth it to clear maps when function ends in android?

Tags: java, android

In android, I make use of hashmaps and sparsearrays and sparseintarrays. In functions I use them sometimes are temporary objects. Before the function ends, it is a good practice to clear the map's data or not?

Thanks

Comment: Are they objects whose scope is limited to the method?

Comment: yes they are limited to the method

Comment: Then no, that accomplishes nothing.

Comment: I thought, if you clear it, then you get back the memory right away instead of waiting for garbage collection. So doesn't that make it work it?

Comment: @omega, you will wait for garbage collection anyway, you cannot directly free the memory in Java. So your call to clear hashmap, sparsearray etc will do nothing at all, maybe it will increase processor load for a little (for some inconsiderable amount like one method call), but it will not affect the process of freeing a memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In android, I make use of hashmaps and sparsearrays and sparseintarrays. In functions I use them sometimes are temporary objects. Before the function ends, it is a good practice to clear the map's data or not?

No, that accomplishes nothing.

> I thought, if you clear it, then you get back the memory right away instead of waiting for garbage collection. So doesn't that make it work it?

Clearing the collection only gets rid of the references to the items in the collection, so you still have to wait for garbage collection to get the memory back.

Answer (score 3):

No.

It is unnecessary to do so. As the hashmap is local to the function, the hashmap will be collected by the garbage collector and it is of no difference if it is empty or not. The contents of the hashmap will also be collected if it has no other reference. It will not be collected any faster in or out of the map.

Therefore clearing it simply wastes your time and clutters your code.

If however you are worried about memory, it must be some pretty large objects. If it is say a `Bitmap`, you can call `bmp.recycle()` to help garbage collection out.